# Accessing facebook user wall posts using C# sdk

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I was trying to retrieve wall posts for a particular user, similar question has been answered here -  [How to get posts of user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845640/how-to-get-posts-of-user) , but for some strange reasons it is not working for me.

I followed the article in the codeplex documentation - [Getting Started with an ASP.NET MVC 3 Website](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%20with%20an%20ASP.NET%20MVC%203%20Website&referringTitle=Getting%20Started)

The AccountController code is similar to https://gist.github.com/899052 and below is the action method which tries to get the posts

```
var facebookId = long.Parse(User.Identity.Name);
var user = this.repository.Get(facebookId);
var fb = new FacebookWebClient(user.AccessToken);
dynamic result = fb.Get("me/feed");
```

but I am always getting an empty array in result.data. I am not quite sure about, whether I need to set any permissions, if so how could I do that?

**Update :**

In the Account Controller, I wasn't requesting the permission in LogOn method, below is the way it could done, which solved the issue

```
public ActionResult LogOn(string returnUrl)
{
   var oAuthClient = new FacebookOAuthClient(FacebookApplication.Current)
   {
       RedirectUri = GetOAuthCallbackUri()
   };
   Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
   parameters.Add("state", returnUrl);
   parameters.Add("scope", "offline_access,read_stream,user_photos,user_videos,publish_stream");
   var loginUri = oAuthClient.GetLoginUrl(parameters);
   return Redirect(loginUri.AbsoluteUri);
 }
```

Before that, I was getting an error mentioned in [5.0.9 error on Exchange code for access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609069/5-0-9-error-on-exchange-code-for-access-token) but I downloaded latest source code a compiled as answered in that post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, ensure you're authorised with the 'read_stream' permission, otherwise you won't be able to access the news feeds.

Secondly, browse to the path...

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[user_id]/feed?access_token=[access_token]
```

...after you have received the access token to see if you get the same results.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to authorize 'read_stream' permission

Comment: @Sambo.. you pointed me to the correct direction. I have added an **update** to the question itself which shows the code fix I have done